# How to create an OpenTelemetry span from ctx in gRPC server stub

Tags: grpc, open-telemetry, google-cloud-trace

My Go gRPC server is instrumented with

1. Google Tracing span exporter:

   ```golang
   import texporter "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-go/exporter/trace"
   ...
   gcp, err := texporter.NewExporter()
   ...
   tracer := trace.NewTracerProvider(trace.WithSyncer(traceExporter),
       trace.WithSampler(trace.AlwaysSample()))
   otel.SetTracerProvider(tracer)
   ```
2. otelgrpc interceptors registered on the gRPC server.

   ```golang
   unaryInterceptors := grpc_middleware.WithUnaryServerChain(
       otelgrpc.UnaryServerInterceptor(),
   )
   streamInterceptors := grpc_middleware.WithStreamServerChain(
       otelgrpc.StreamServerInterceptor(),
   )
   ```

Now I'm **trying to create a trace span** inside the RPC implementation so I can have child spans for the method e.g.:

```golang
func (s *srv) Test(ctx context.Context, req *pb.Request) (*pb.TestResponse, error) {
    // create a span here
    span1 := [??????].Start()
    doWork1()
    span1.End()

    span2 := [??????].Start()
    doWork2()
    span2.End()
    ...
}
```

However it is wildly unclear [from the OpenTelemetry docs](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/go/instrumentation/) how does one do that.

Closest I've gotten is `otel.GetTracerProvider().Tracer("some string here???")` providing a `Start(ctx)(ctx,Span)`. But it is not clear to me what string to provide here (my exporter doesn't have a url like the docs indicate) and this seems quite inconvenient.

I'm thinking there's something like a `otelgrpc.SpanFromCtx(ctx)` method somewhere that pulls the tracer+creates a span with the rpc ctx that I'm not finding. Sadly the docs are quite lacking on OT+gRPC+Go.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-go), you should use itself to create span rather than opentelemetry.

You can create a new span like this:

```golang
    // Create custom span.
    tracer := otel.TraceProvider().Tracer("example.com/trace")
    err = func(ctx context.Context) error {
        ctx, span := tracer.Start(ctx, "foo")
        defer span.End()

        // Do some work.

        return nil
    }(ctx)
```

For more detail, you can reference [OpenTelemetry Google Cloud Trace Exporter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-go/blob/main/exporter/trace/README.md)

Comment: Yeah I see that  in the documentation, but I doubt that is a good idea. You're initializing tracer again and again all over the place (e.g. in each gRPC service type, or worse, in each RPC) and potentially with different names. I think the best way to do this is to carry the `trace.TraceProvider` instance around in the gRPC service types and use it to initialize.  Your suggestion would make a lot of sense for a "library" that gets imported in code (e.g. redis-go) and therefore doesn't have access to the Tracer, so it can initialize its own as a singleton.